# How can I import a javascript file from my typescript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I am using Typescript & angular 2. I have an EncryptionService:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
  import './lib/hmac256-enc64';

  @Injectable()
  export class EncryptionService {
    constructor() {
    }
    hmacSha256(message: string, secret: string) {
      return CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    }
  }
```

I want to include './lib/hmac256-enc64'; (CryptoJS) But on runtime I get the error:

**detected as register but didn't execute.**

How can I include a Js file as a dependency in my EncryptionService?

Comment: This post got it working for me. Registering it in system.js map.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to download the CryptoJS type definitions:

```
$ typings install cryptojs --ambient --save
```

Then add a reference to the type definitions and import CryptoJS :

```
/// <reference path="./typings/main.d.ts" />

import * as CryptoJS from "cryptojs"
```

If import does not work use the old external modules:

```
import CryptoJS = require('cryptojs');
```

You can then use [`CryptoJS.HmacSHA256`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts#L455)

Please note that I have never used CryptoJS with TypeScript so I can't be 100% sure about this working...

Comment: Thanks for the try.. didn't work though.